# Retry a connection on timeout in Java

Tags: java

I have a method (below) that pulls down and returns the source of a webpage as a String. It all works fine and dandy, but when the connection times out, the program throws an exception and exits. Is there a better method to do this that would allow it to try again on timeout, or is there a way to do it within this method?

```
public static String getPage(String theURL) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(theURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        exitprint();
    }
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = url.openStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        exitprint();
    }
    int ptr = 0;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while ((ptr = is.read()) != -1) {
            buffer.append((char)ptr);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        exitprint();
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a refactoring of your code that should retry the download `N` times. Haven't tested it though, but it should kick you off in the right direction.

```
public static String getPage(String theURL) {

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(theURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        exitprint();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        try {
            InputStream is = url.openStream();

            int ptr = 0;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((ptr = is.read()) != -1)
                buffer.append((char)ptr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            continue;
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    throw new SomeException("Failed to download after " + N + " attepmts");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely set me on the right track. Only issue I ran into was buffer being out of scope in the return statement - so I stuck it up under the while statement, before the catch.

Comment: You may want to check the HTTP response code too. url.getResponseCode();

Answer (score 2):

I think AOP and Java annotations is a good option. I would recommend to use a read-made mechanism from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-retryonfailure.html):

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, delay = 10)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper function around it and allow the connect exception to propogate out. Then you can loop calling your existing function while you receive connect exception upto some max retries.

This is better than embedding a for loop in your existing function because it logically separates retry logic from mainline code. And it's easier to read and understand as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the whole thing in a `while` loop:

```
while (true) {

  try {
    ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
    continue;
  }

  return buffer.toString();
}
```

The `return` statement will break you out of the loop.  You might also want to keep track of the number of attempts and stop after 5-10, for politeness, but that's the basic shape of it.

**Edit**

The better version, based on comments:

```
int retries = 10;
for (int i = 0 ; i < retries ; i++) {

  try {
    ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
    continue;
  }

  return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: or use a `for` to make clearer that it's a limited retry?  Anyways, +1 for "politeness" :-)

Comment: Oh right, yes indeed.  Some people like to use `for` to only loop a certain number of times :P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
try {
    is = url.openStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    exitprint();
}
```

you can try set longer timeout and you can still handle timeout exception by catching [it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)

```
try {
    URLConnection con= url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000); 
    con.setReadTimeout(50000);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    //here you can still handle timeout like try again under certain conditions
}
```