# How to make the client wait for the server socket connection?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, wifip2p

I am using wifi direct to communicate between two mobile devices. I have setup sockets to send and receive messages. Everything works fine if I start the server device first(owner) and then the client device(member). I want to start any device in any order and still manage to send messages.

Currently, client waits for 5 secs and if no connection is available, then it stops looking for the server. I want the client to continue looking for the server even after time out till it finds the server connection. I have tried doing this and I am not successful yet in implementing this.

Initial client code:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address.getHostAddress(), SERVER_PORT), TIME_OUT);
            socketCreator = new SocketCreator(socket, handler);
            new Thread(socketCreator).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

Modified like this:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket.bind(null);
            while(!connectedToServer) {
                try {
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address.getHostAddress(), SERVER_PORT),
                            TIME_OUT);
                    socketCreator = new SocketReadWriter(socket, handler);
                    new Thread(socketCreator).start();
                    connectedToServer = true;
                } catch (ConnectException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error while connecting. " + e.getMessage());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i(TAG,"Exception "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is missing in my code? How can I make it work?

I am getting this error continuously:

```
Exception java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312794/retry-a-connection-on-timeout-in-java. Also, you should call `socket.close()` in a `finally` block, not a `catch`.

Comment: I tried again.. I am getting this: Exception java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `new Socket()` every time.  Failing to connect to the remote server invalidates the socket for any further use.

> If connect() fails, consider the state of the socket as unspecified. Portable applications should close the socket and create a new one for reconnecting.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html

Since you are running this on Android - I guess you are not seeing the "Socket closed" error when trying to call `connect` twice.

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    connector: while (true)
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket();

        try
        {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 9999), 2000);
            this.doSomethingElseWithConnectedSocket(socket);
            break connector; // break out of the while loop
        }
        catch (ConnectException e)
        {
            // ignore because worthless
        }

        try
        {
             socket.close();
        }
        catch(Throwable x)
        {
             // ignore
        }

        System.out.println("Unable to connect to server ");

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}

public void doSomethingElseWithConnectedSocket(Socket value)
{
     value.close(); // close for no good reason
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. I have one more question. How do I close the socket here? I mean, where should I put it?

Comment: You can close the socket from anywhere anytime.  You could put `value.close()` inside of `doSomethingElseWIthConnectedSocket()`

Comment: Failing to connect does not close the socket automatically. You have to close it. But you can't use it to try another connection. `socket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. A `ConnectException` would have been thrown.