# auto connect in case of error

Tags: java, jackson

i am working on android app , I often get HTTP error 500 when i try to access the url due to bad connectivity which causes my app to fail . Response returned from URL is in JSON format so in order to Parse this json i used jackson api

```
JsonNode monthlyUrlNode  = objectMapper.readValue(url, JsonNode.class);
```

**In case of failure i want to reconnect to url with a delay of 30 seconds**

i referred this [Retry a connection on timeout in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312794/retry-a-connection-on-timeout-in-java) , but it is not of much use to me

Comment: Could you share the code with modifications from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312794/retry-a-connection-on-timeout-in-java? My recommendation is that you should acquire stream at your application end, and then use it to process JSON. Because in the case of an exception you can handle the network appropriately as per your logic rather than depending upon Jackson API to realise your error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a Proxy object?  Proxy let's you wrap an interface in a way that you can perform the same intervention independent of the method being called.  Let's assume you've already created a client object for accessing interface SomeService.  Then you can create a proxy class with a 30-second retry built in:

```
public class ServiceProxy implements InvocationHandler {
   private final SomeService realClient;
   public ServiceProxy(SomeService realClientObject) {
      this.realClient = realClientObject;
   }
   @Override
   public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
      Object result = method.invoke(realClient, args);
      if (result instanceof URL) {
          JsonNode urlNode = objectMapper.readValue(url, JsonNode.class);
          if (some condition on urlNode) {
             // Wait and retry
             Thread.sleep(30000);
             result = method.invoke(realClient, args);
          }
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

You create the proxy object by passing it the original interface, like:

```
public class ProxyFactory {
    public static SomeService get(SomeService originalClient) {
        return (SomeService)Proxy.newProxyInstance(SomeService.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{SomeService.class},
                new ServiceProxy(originalClient));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this sort of fine control, do not pass a URL to Jackson. Use an appropriate HTTP library to read the content from the URL into memory, retrying as needed, and then feed it to Jackson.